# How to write rest api for magento-1.9.?

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

We need REST API's to build mobile application. I am beginner of rest api. How to write REST API for Magento-1.9.?

Comment: Magento 1.9 support is no more Upgrade to 2.x for Rest APIs

Answer (score 2):

**Magento 1.x REST API**

**1) How to configure Magento REST and oAuth settings.**

[Check here](http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/)

**2) Magento official guide for REST API.**

[check Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)

**3) How to build custom Magento Rest API**

[Check Here](https://www.ipragmatech.com/magento-rest-api-two-hours-part-one/)

I hope you can be built your one REST API now. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete guidance in **Magento 1.x REST API** Dev docs with section wise

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest-api-index.html

**And for module wise**

- [Authentication](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html)
- [Sales Orders](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html)
- [Products](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html)
- [Customers](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html)
- [Inventory](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/inventory.html)

> PHP examples for [REST](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-PHPExamples)